# CSS3: add rounded corners to images

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add rounded corners to a frame but it only works in mozilla and not in chrome or IE.

[image: Rounded corners]

I am not adding the `border-radius` property to the image tag but to canvas tag instead

```
canvas {border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;}
```

Can anyone suggest something?

The website is [n1bar.com](http://n1bar.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're setting the radius for all browsers, like this:

```
canvas {
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; /* CSS3 */

    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; /* CSS3 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little cleaner version:

```
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
```

Essentially the order is "Top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left".